# API limit for Office365 REST APIs

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to know the limit for API calls per minute/hour for Office365 REST APIs (People, Mail).

Is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have information about the current throttling algorithm, but please be aware that we are constantly revisiting and tweaking it. Any algorithm we share now does not mean we are committing to supporting that mechanism in the future.

There is no hard request rate enforced on the Exchange side.  The way current throttling works is that it allows each caller by default 30 minutes (1800000 millisec) per hour of solid thread time on the server.  It is a lazy evaluated “token bucket” impl with a rolling window – basically you “recharge” at a rate of 1 second per 2 clock seconds, and you spend clock time on the server.  When you get to zero, you are throttled for about 5 minutes.

Hope that helps!